# Calculate time difference between two columns into another column AFTER\BEFORE INSERT in table

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

i have a DB for managing an airport. I want to try to calculate the time difference between columns ArrivingDate and DepartingDate (both are DATETIME type) into a third column called Flight_time (TIME type) after any INSERT in the table FLIGHT_SCHEDULES.

I tried to create a trigger for doing that, but with no success. I have already read some stuff on the internet about my error but couldn't find something which solve my dilemma.

```
This is the table:

CREATE TABLE FLIGHT_SCHEDULES(
    id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Flight INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    Airplane INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    DepartingDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
    ArrivingDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
    Flight_time TIME DEFAULT '00:00:00',
    CONSTRAINT flight_unique UNIQUE (Flight),
    CONSTRAINT fk_scheduled_flight_id FOREIGN KEY (Flight) REFERENCES FLIGHTS(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_scheduled_airplane_id FOREIGN KEY (Airplane) REFERENCES AIRPLANES(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);

This is the trigger I created:

delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER calculate_flightTime2 BEFORE INSERT ON FLIGHT_SCHEDULES FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE FLIGHT_SCHEDULES
    SET NEW.Flight_time = TIMEDIFF(new.ArrivingDate, new.DepartingDate);
END //
```

I can create the trigger with no problems, but the I try to insert a new row in the table I receive the following error message:

Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'flight_schedules' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.  0.000 sec

Note that I tried to create an AFTER trigger too, but the result was the same.

Answer (score 2):

Usually it's not a good idea to materialize values that can be calculated from others. This bears the risk of inconsistencies. What happens if you change the arriving time for example?

So it's probably best if you drop the column `Flight_time`.

```
ALTER TABLE FLIGHT_SCHEDULES
            DROP Flight_time;
```

For convenience you can then create a view, that includes the calculated value.

```
CREATE VIEW FLIGHT_SCHEDULES_WITH_FLIGHT_TIME
AS
SELECT *,
       timediff(ArrivingDate, DepartingDate) Flight_time
       FROM FLIGHT_SCHEDULES;
```

In MySQL 8+ you could alternatively use a [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html). That's a safe way as the DBMS guarantees consistency like that.

```
ALTER TABLE FLIGHT_SCHEDULES
            ADD Flight_time time AS timediff(ArrivingDate, DepartingDate);
```

But if you insist on using a trigger, you don't need an `UPDATE` to set a value in the `new` pseudo record. Just an assignment is enough.

```
...
SET NEW.Flight_time = TIMEDIFF(new.ArrivingDate, new.DepartingDate);
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, now, after reading what you just wrote, I think that it will be a good idea to calculate the flight time in a VIEW than calculate it directly in table. I forgot to think about what happens if one of the dates(arriving/departing) will change.

Answer (score 0):

It is a restriction of mysql so you don t end up in an endless loop.

Try something like this.

```
CREATE TRIGGER calculate_flightTime2 
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON FLIGHT_SCHEDULES 
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NEW.Flight_time = '00:00:00' THEN
    SET NEW.Flight_time = TIMEDIFF(new.ArrivingDate, new.DepartingDate);
  END IF;
END
```